# Building iPhone app with GData XML fails: undefined symbols (for architecture i386)

Tags: iphone, xml, xcode, ios, libxml2

I've tried to include GData XML into my current project. So far without success, however, building fails due to an error of a kind that's out of my scope..:

[image]

Since I am building for iPhone (and iPhone Simulator, for the sake of completeness), I don't know why it cares about i386 anyway. But then again the whole matter of including libxml2 is a bit beyond my comfort zone - I'm doing this for the first time.

For setting up all the flags and search paths I was referring to Step 4 of [**this tutorial**](http://johntwang.com/blog/2009/06/08/how-to-use-google-apis-with-iphone-sdk/). I was unable to add the OTHER_CFLAGS flag, since a key of the same name exists in *LLVM GCC 4.2 - Language* already. So I tried to set it to *-DDEBUG=1* there, but that didn't change anything.

So, how do I get things to work properly? It seems like documentation on GData XML is sparse - can you recommend any ressource that explains things better than the link I found?

**Edit:**

Since koregan asked this in his comment, I'd like to add that it doesn't compile for iPhone Simulator and the actual device. If building for the device the error is a slightly different one (without the i386 part) however:

[image]

Comment: The simulator runs on your mac so has i386 architecture. 
Do you have libraries built for both arm and i386 for GData?

Comment: @koregan: see my edit for what happens if I build for the device. I have not built any libraries, I just added the XMLSupport folder to my project and set the flags and paths for libxml2 as described in the tutorial I found...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geez! Got it.

Did import GDataXMLNode.h in my apps pch file. Found the solution in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926777/something-wrong-in-my-program-by-using-gdata-xmlsupport/3110259#3110259). Could have thought of that. Wouldn't you have? Stupid me.