# linking error Ipad

Tags: ios, ipad

Hi am having this error when I am trying to compile my application. Can any one please let me what this error is?

Thanks

```
Ld /Users/DineshParchuri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Graph_Theory-bxoahqkbiemabledhmfyzkqpotjr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Graph_Theory.app/Graph_Theory normal i386
    cd "/Users/DineshParchuri/Desktop/3:28:11/Graph_Theory"
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk -L/Users/DineshParchuri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Graph_Theory-bxoahqkbiemabledhmfyzkqpotjr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/DineshParchuri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Graph_Theory-bxoahqkbiemabledhmfyzkqpotjr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/DineshParchuri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Graph_Theory-bxoahqkbiemabledhmfyzkqpotjr/Build/Intermediates/Graph_Theory.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Graph_Theory.build/Objects-normal/i386/Graph_Theory.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/DineshParchuri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Graph_Theory-bxoahqkbiemabledhmfyzkqpotjr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Graph_Theory.app/Graph_Theory

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MyTableCell", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Graph_TheoryViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MyTableCell", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Graph_TheoryViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

specifies that an Objective-C class named MyTableCell is not (completely) defined and a call to this undefined class is made in Graph_TheoryViewController.m

Check the Graph_TheoryViewController.m file and see if you implemented MyTableCell if you have (I assume) class with that name defined in one of the included headers.

If this class is declared elsewhere, you may be missing method implementations in the appropriate .m file (most likely MyTableCell.m)

Answer (score -1):

This very same error drove me to the brink of insanity when I tried to include GData XML into one of my apps. The cause of the problem was that I included GDataXMLNode.h in my apps pch file - see my [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5091588/416600).

If you're trying the same (using GData XML) this might be your solution, too. If not, try commenting out stuff in your pch file anyway - to be honest, I still don't know the exact logic behind this error, any explanations welcome...